# How can I delete a particular column ( key value) in the table (json) with Javascript and Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

```
[{
    "name": "employeeOne",
    "age": 22,
    "position": "UI",
    "city": "Chennai"
},
{
    "name": "employeeTwo",
    "age": 23,
    "position": "UI",
    "city": "Bangalore"
}
]
```

If I delete "Position"
key & value from the json the result should be like[

```
[{
    "name": "employeeOne",
    "age": 22,
    "city": "Chennai"
}, {
    "name": "employeeTwo",
    "age": 23,
    "city": "Bangalore"
}]
```

If we have list of employee in a table I want to delete all the employees position column only. How can I achieve this with JavaScript and Typescript

I tried
`const output = delete employee.position`
but getting an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data = [{
                "name": "employeeOne",
                "age": 22,
                "position": "UI",
                "city": "Chennai"
            },
            {
                "name": "employeeTwo",
                "age": 23,
                "position": "UI",
                "city": "Bangalore"
            }
          ];

data.forEach( item => {delete item.position;});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Why use `Object.keys` here? Just `data.forEach(item => delete item.position)` should be enough.

Comment: Yeah, that is a perfect solution.

Comment: Thank you! happy that I got one lesson today :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of objects there.  You would have to loop through the array, deleting the property in each object individually.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the delete operation

pseudo:

> foreach obj in jsonArray
>   {
>   delete obj["position"];
>   }

also works:

> obj[position]
>   obj.position

http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/